# Error: Failed to create keystore in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I' trying to create a key for signing my app and I got this error:

Failed to create keystore.

[image]

How should I do?

Android Studio: Electric Eel Patch 2

Android Gradle Plugin: 7.4.2

Gradle Version: 7.5.1-bin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/install.1111/e12002/oimscrn011.htm#INOIM1372) uses the same keytool under the hood (it is Oracle Identity Management's KeyStore), but when I changed my password to conform with the requirements given at that link, and made the Keystore and Key passwords the same, the error no longer appeared.

Specifically: "A valid password can contain 6 to 30 characters, begin with an alphabetic character, and use only alphanumeric characters and special characters like Underscore (_), Dollar ($), Pound (#). The password must contain at least one number."

Comment: You should expand on what the link addresses, the link may break and your answer may become less useful.

Comment: I have `сYb0uO9sU7y8hZ` key (autogenerated on one site) for all password fields, what is wrong with that? The same error. I tried another typed randomly by myself some letters and some digits (14 length) and it worked. Stupid...

Comment: mb it doesn't allow to use zero numbers, anyway I don't want to test it anymore, hate this tool which doesn't even tell the reason

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the validity number is Persian

- Change the format to English from Windows settings
- Exit Android Studio and re-enter. Then test

Answer (score 0):

Two more issues that prevent key store creation:

- The keystore file key must be the same as the upload key
- The State field cannot contain a comma